# Personne dans sa famille ne s'en apercevait, jusqu'au jour où il grillait / a grillé toute l'électricité de la maison

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait

*Le journal de Carrie* de Candace Bushnell :

> ...j'ai écrit un livre entier sur un garçon qui se transformait en
> télé. Personne dans sa famille ne s'en apercevait, jusqu'au jour où il
> **grillait** toute l'électricité de la maison.

L'auteure emploie l'imparfait *se transformait en télé* et *ne s'en apercevait* parce qu'il s'agit de descriptions. Mais pourquoi utilise-t-elle l'imparfait dans *il grillait toute l'électricité* ? On parle ici d'une action unique et non d'une série d'actions, et ce n'est pas une description non plus.

Comment: Hypothèse: erreur du traducteur ?

Comment: @Greg C'est ce que je pensais moi aussi.

Comment: Je suis presque certaine que l'anglais avait le simple past: until the day he blew out all the electricity.

Answer (score 1):

L'imparfait a ici d'une valeur [modale](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4198). Il sert à indiquer des faits hypothétiques, imaginaires.

Le passé composé (*jusqu'au jour où il a grillé toute l'électricité de la maison*) donnerait à cet événement une réalité qu'il n'a pas.

Le texte original est le suivant :

> *I wrote a whole book about a boy who turned into a TV, and no one in his family noticed until he used up all the electricity in the house.*

Il utilise le préterit.

Sa traduction en espagnol utilise le présent, temps qui aurait été aussi un bon choix en français :

> *escribí todo un libro sobre un chico que se convierte en televisor, y nadie en su familia lo nota hasta que consume toda la electricidad de la casa.*

Comment: Il ne serait pas possible d'employer le conditionnel à la place ? _Personne dans sa famille ne s'en apercevait, jusqu'au jour où il **grillerait** toute l'électricité de la maison_

Comment: Le conditionnel est possible oui, sinon, le présent aurait pu être aussi utilisé *j'ai écrit un livre entier sur un garçon qui se transforme en télé. Personne dans sa famille ne s'en aperçoit, jusqu'au jour où il grille toute l'électricité de la maison.*

Answer (score 1):

On peut imaginer que l'événement se produise régulièrement.
Formulé autrement : à chaque fois que ce garçon grillait l'électricité de la maison, sa famille s'apercevait qu'il se transformait en télévision, avant de l'oublier rapidement.

Peut-être une façon étrange de dire que ce garçon manquait d'attention ? La suite du texte ou la version originale pourraient nous en dire plus.

Comment: Merci. _à chaque fois que ce garçon grillait l'électricité de la maison, sa famille s'apercevait qu'il se transformait en télévision, avant de l'oublier rapidement._ Ce n'est pas très réaliste, à mon avis. // Je ne retrouve plus cette page, mais d'aussi loin que je me souvienne, il n'y avait pas de suite à l'histoire que la narratrice avait écrite.

Comment: Je suis d'accord, ce n'est guère réaliste. Mais pas moins qu'un garçon se transformant en télévision :-)